# How to signal that file has been selected when the input type="file" is hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I have done some styling to my input form for files so that it looks how the rest of the form looks, everything is working perfectly fine but I just noticed you cannot tell when you have got a file selected. Is there a way of being able to set the `<p>` tag which I have used as a mask to display the given filename/path? Below is a js fiddle with the code I have used.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6xATE/1)

For some strange reason.. It's not working in the fiddle even though I have copied over the code.. anyway, is there a way that inside the Choose Track: field i can get it to display the chosen track? Thanks.

Comment: It's not working in your fiddle because you haven't included jQuery. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/6xATE/1/

Comment: Cheers, but that wasn't the actual issue, that was just a problem with the fiddle itself. Just noticed the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this: ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xATE/3/))

```
$('.fileinput').change(function() {
    $('.fileInputMask').text($(this).val());
});
```